# Status 204: response.json() - Caught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at manageRequest

Tags: javascript

I've searched for this kind of error but unfortunately didn't found help.

I have an API written in Python (django).

When doing a put/post request, the backend responds with data (JSON).

The problem now: When I perform a 204-Response, .json() throws an exception.

What I do not understand: The backend works fine with Postman (see screenshot).
[image: Postman]

Here is the code which is causing the exception:

```
const response = await fetch(url, reqData)
data  = await response.json()
```

It seems to be something related to the fetch()-api since postman gives me a correct result (with status=204). Also, if I change the backend status to e.g. 200, everything works just fine, but since the request is for deleting in the first place, I want to use 204.

Error from catch-block:

> Caught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at manageRequest

Comment: Don't use status code 204 then. 204 means __No Content__.

Comment: And the browser is apparently ignoring the actual contents because of that interpretation of the status code.

Comment: @Barmar yeah thats the problem here. Was confused, b/c I got the expected result with postman

Answer (score 3):

The body of a response with status code `204` is ignored, since this status code is used for `No Content` responses. [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) says:

> A 204 response is terminated by the first empty line after the header
> fields because it cannot contain a message body.

Use status code `200` if you want to indicate that the request was successful and you're returning new data. The fact that it's a `DELETE` request rather than `GET` or `POST` should not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Writing
**HttpResponse(204)**
instead of
**HttpResponse(status=204)**
surprisingly worked for me.

Comment: No surprise here. It's because the first argument is (content). So, 204 is passed to (content), and (status) is preserved to default (200)